# The property 'Command' was not found in type 'InvokeCommandAction'

Tags: windows-phone-7

my xaml：

```
<:Interaction.Triggers>
    <:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <:InvokeCommandAction 
            Command="{Binding HelloCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=List}" />
    </:EventTrigger>
<:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and I get an exception

> The property 'Command' was not found in type 'InvokeCommandAction'.

Answer (score 1):

I just came cross with this issue after I accidentally uninstalled

> Microsoft Expression Blend SDK for Windows Phone OS 7.1

This behaivor `InvokeCommandAction` is included in this SDK only, not the previous Blend SDK for Windows Phone 7.

You will need to download and install [Windows Phone SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570), and this Blend SDK 7.1 will be automatically included in the installation.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Command` property isn't present in WP7, even though `InvokeCommandAction` is.  You may want to look at using EventToCommand from MVVM Light to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: The Command property isn't present in WP7 ? but I watched some example can use that

Comment: More specifically, the Command property isn't part of InvokeCommandAction on WP7, although it is on other versions of Silverlight.

Comment: Actually it is, you just need the lastest Windows Phone SDK (7.1). :)